# How do I pass Bing Web Search API Data from Django to display in React

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I've got it where I can print the data from my search result in a Django folder called api.py using Python. But now, how do I move this data into react to display it? Could anyone help give me a detailed way to do this. Much Thanks in advance!

I also have the Bing API key stored in a .env file currently in the same file level as the api.py file.

Bing Web Search API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-web-search/reference/endpoints

**code:** *in api.py file*

```
`from pprint import pprint
import requests
from decouple import config

subscription_key = config('subscription_key', default='')

search_url = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search"
search_term = 'iphone 13'

headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key}
params = {"q": search_term, "textDecorations": True, "textFormat": "HTML"}
response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
response.raise_for_status()
search_results = response.json()

pages = search_results\['webPages'\]
results = pages\['value'\]
pprint(results\[0\])`
```

[**This is the data I'm getting in the terminal:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pl7b.png)

I've tried looking through stackoverflow and the whole internet, haven't found anyone really using this API..

Update: errors **

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

why you don't create a GET api in Django app and place this whole logic inside view DRF view. For example map this endpoint on your view

```
/my-view
```

. **And finally call this api from your react app**

**Detailed Answer:**

**STEP 1:**
Create a view in your views.py:

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
`from pprint import pprint
import requests
from decouple import config

```
def my_view(request):
    subscription_key = config('subscription_key', default='')

    search_url = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search"
    search_term = 'iphone 13'

    headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key}
    params = {"q": search_term, "textDecorations": True, 
    "textFormat": "HTML"}
    response = requests.get(search_url,headers=headers,params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    search_results = response.json()

    pages = search_results\['webPages'\]
    results = pages\['value'\]
    pprint(results\[0\])`
    return results
```

**STEP 2:**
you'll need to map your view function to a URL. Open your app's urls.py file and add a URL pattern for your view. For example:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('my-view/', views.my_view, name='my-view'),
]
```

**STEP 3:**

Create a component in React :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('http://your-django-api-url/my-view/');
                setData(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My Component</h1>
            {data ? (
                <ul>
                    {data.map((item) => (
                        <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

**Step 4:**

Render this component :

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>My React App</h1>
            <MyComponent />
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: This might be a good suggestion, but the answer is lacking in necessary detail.

Comment: Could you check my repo and see what I am missing https://gitlab.com/JesseMorris91/bing-web-search

Comment: @jessemorris where exactly you are stuck and what is your error

Comment: @tousifNoor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78244943/how-do-i-update-my-bing-web-api-search-results-in-react-js-after-submitting-quer