# How do I update my Bing web API search results in React.js after submitting query in search bar (serp format)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, bing-api

I am using the Bing Web Search API, and I am accessing the data when typing a query into the search bar I created. But I have not been able to get the data to display in my search results when submitting the search bar query. I am trying to access the elements in 'value' which is inside of 'webPages' as shown in the picture below:
[search engine data]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRBjB.png

Bing Web Search: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-web-search/reference/endpoints

If anyone could help with a detailed response it would be greatly appreciated!

useSearch.js:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/search';
const API_KEY = '0760f20a58f340a4ba3ce10857c43142'

const useSearch = ( {searchTerm} ) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('');


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            if (!searchTerm) return;
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}`, {
                    headers: {
                        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': API_KEY,
                    },
                    params: {
                        'q': `${searchTerm}`,
                        'count': 10,
                        'mkt': 'en-us',
                    },
                });
                setData(response.data.webPages.value);
                // shows data from search bar
                console.log(response.data);

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [searchTerm]);

    return data;

};

export default useSearch;
```

SearchResults.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import TileItems from './TileItems';
import useSearch from './UseSearch';

const SearchResults = () => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
    const { data } = useSearch({ searchTerm: searchData });

    return (
      <div className=''>
        <main className={`main-container ${theme}`}>
          <section className="eighty" id="item-tiles">
            <h1>Search Results</h1>
            {data ? (
                <ul>
                  {data.map((i) => (
                      <TileItems
                          key={i.id}
                          image={i.thumbnailUrl}
                          title={i.name}
                          description={i.snippet}
                          website={i.url}
                      />
                  ))}
                </ul>
                ) : (
                  <p>Loading...</p>
                )}
          </section>
          <section id="item-tiles-right" className="twenty">
            <h2 id='col-2-header'>News</h2>
               {video ? (
                  <ul>
                    {/* this section is still under development */}
                    {video.map((v) => (
                        <iframe
                          id='ytplayer'
                          src={v.contentUrl}
                          frameborder='0'
                          allow='autoplay; encrypted-media'
                          width='100%'
                          height='360'
                          title='video'
                        />
                     ))}
                  </ul>
                  ) : (
                    <p>Loading...</p>
                  )}
          </section>
        </main>
      </div>
  );
};
```

Nav.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './NavBar.css';
import logo_light from '../../assets/spigot-logo.png';
import logo_dark from '../../assets/logo_light2.png';
import search_icon_light from '../../assets/search-w.png';
import search_icon_dark from '../../assets/search-b.png';
import toggle_light from '../../assets/night.png';
import toggle_dark from '../../assets/day.png';
import useSearch from '../UseSearch';


function NavBar({theme, setTheme, setSearchTerm}) {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const { data } = useSearch({ searchTerm: searchQuery});
  // console.log(setSearchQuery);

  /* ternary clause to change theme between light and dark mode */
  const toggle_mode = () => {
    theme == 'light' ? setTheme('dark') : setTheme('light');
  }

  return (
    <div className='navbar' >
        <img src={theme == 'light' ? logo_light : logo_dark} alt='' className='logo' />
        <ul className='nav-list'>
          <li>SEARCH</li>
        </ul>
      <div className='search-box'>
        <form>
           <input  className='search-bar' type='text' placeholder='Search' onChange={(e) => 
            setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}></input>
        </form>
        <img className='search-icon' src={theme == 'light' ? search_icon_light : 
           search_icon_dark} alt='' />
      </div>
        <img onClick={() => {toggle_mode()}} src={theme == 'light' ? toggle_light : 
           toggle_dark} alt='' className='toggle-icon'></img>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavBar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data returned from `useSearch` needs to be an array in order for you to map it, so in your `useSearch` hook you need to only get the `value` array if you want to only render the results.

```js
// in useSearch hook
// we only take the array of webpages value
// looking from your console.log screenshot
  setData(response.data.webPages.value);
```

You are trying to map your `searchData` which is a string. In order for you to map the actual api data you would need to use the data returned from your `useSearch` hook

```js
   // this is the API data
      // no need to destruct
    const data = useSearch({ searchTerm: searchData });

    // replace searchData with data
   {data ? (
                <ul>
                  {data.map((i) => (
                      <TileItems
                          key={i.id}
                          image={i.thumbnailUrl}
                          title={i.name}
                          description={i.snippet}
                          website={i.url}
                      />
                  ))}
                </ul>
                ) : (
                  <p>Loading...</p>
                )}
```

Lemme know if this fixes your problem

Comment: So that is actually something I have tried. with setData(response.data.webPages.value) with data.map but I either get: 'searchTerm' is not defined error. Or I get cannot access 'searchTerm' before intialization. So I think it is maybe trying to load it before something is typed into the input? @mssp

Comment: So I got rid of that error by moving line 19 before line 20. but when I submit the query into the search bar the data just wont load. It's doing nothing @mssp                                      
 const SearchResults = ({}) => {

    const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
    // const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [video, setVideo] = useState(null);
    const [ad, setAd] = useState(null);
19 const [ searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    const { data } = useSearch({ searchTerm: searchTerm});

Comment: all of the data in the console goes away after submitting the query, and does not load it into data.map @mssp

Comment: I see, I made a small mistake, sorry. You don't need to destruct the data when using it , you can just  `const  data  = useSearch({ searchTerm: searchData });` . I will correct my answer

Comment: Also there is a possibility that the search term is not correct. When you say the data disappear with console.log, did you also check the response in your network browser tab?